# Rewriting URLs only if path start/end with condition

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm using this rewriting rule :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([a-z\-A-Z0-9]+)-model/([a-z\-A-Z0-9]+)/$ [NC]
RewriteRule . p.php?model=%1&media=%2 [L,QSA]
```

so a working URL looks like this :

```
example.com/foo-model/foo/
```

However if I type this URL it works as well :

```
example.com/random_path/foo-model/foo/random_path/
```

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a ^ to the beginning of the Rewrite condition should do the trick:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z\-A-Z0-9]+)-model/([a-z\-A-Z0-9]+)/$ [NC]
RewriteRule . p.php?model=%1&media=%2 [L,QSA]
```

That will tell the rule to start searching at the first '/', not any '/' in the URL.